# Which tense should I use in "I was talking about … when she started to talk about …"?

Tags: difference, tense, tense-agreement

I was talking to her about something else when she suddenly started to talk about what he **had been** up to these days.

I was talking to her about something else when she suddenly started to talk about what he **was** up to these days.

I was talking to her about something else when she suddenly started to talk about what he **has been** up to these days.

I was talking to her about something else when she suddenly started to talk about what he **is** up to these days.

Which of the above sentences grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with these sentences is that you shouldn't really use "these days" when using anything other than the present tense.

With regards to the tenses, this is a rather complicated part of English. Because the head verb ("started") is in the **perfect** tense, you need to imagine all the tenses in the subsequent clause being **brought forward** by one step (pluperfect -> perfect, perfect -> present).

There are differences in these meanings:

- "I was talking to her about something else when she suddenly started to talk about what he **had been up to**" - this means what he was doing at some point **before** she spoke to you (imagine it being in the **perfect**)
- "I was talking to her about something else when she suddenly started to talk about what he **was up to**" - this means what he was doing around **the same time** as when she spoke (imagine it being in the **present**)
- "I was talking to her about something else when she suddenly started to talk about what he **has been up to**" - roughly the same meaning as the previous one, but I wouldn't use it personally
- "I was talking to her about something else when she suddenly started to talk about what he **is up to**" - this one to me feels grammatically incorrect. I would never use the present when the head verb is in the perfect.

Answer (score -1):

All are grammatically correct, and there is little practical difference in their meaning. Noting only the words that change with each example,

> "had been up to these days" indicates the actions are in the past, although recent;
>
> "was up to these days" could indicate the actions are in the present and/or near past;
>
> "has been up to these days" indicates the actions are in the near past;
>
> "is up to these days" indicates the actions are presently happening and ongoing.

**"These days"** keeps all of these examples in the present, recent or near past.

Comment: "Was up to" is not necessarily confined to the past. It could include ghe present set in the past tense due to backshifting.

Comment: Has been/have been can describe events that occurred only in the past. *I've been eating a lot lately* does not always signal actions that carry through to the present.

Comment: what about the "Had Been" one?

Comment: @JimReynolds- I think my edits have addressed your concerns, but please let me know if they haven't (or edit my answer accordingly). Also, I think lekon chekon's question in the comment above is for you. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I was talking about something else when she started suddenly talking about what he was up-to these days.  In your sentences, suddenly, as in “suddenly started,” is a misplaced modifier.